# jQuery Mobile Form won't submit with style attribute on button

Tags: jquery, mobile

Why would adding a style attribute disable a button from submitting the form while using jquery mobile?

If I remove the style attribute, the form submits correctly.  After adding the style attribute clicking the button has no effect on the page (the form will not submit)

ie..

```
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmitResponse" name="btnSubmitResponse" value="Send Message" class="btn" style="width:80px;"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using: data-inline="true" as attribute, might be it will works for you. It is working find with your code but its allowed you to click on only first 80px part. Let try and let me know updates!

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmitResponse" name="btnSubmitResponse" value="Send Message" data-inline="true" style="width: 80px;"  />
```